# How to convert a "HH:MM:SS" string to seconds with PHP?

Tags: php, time, date-conversion

Is there a native way of doing `"HH:MM:SS" to seconds` with PHP 5.3 rather than doing a split on the colon's and multipling out each section the relevant number to calculate the seconds?

---

For example in Python you can do :

```
string time = "00:01:05";
double seconds = TimeSpan.Parse(time).TotalSeconds;
```

---

Comment: The equivalent would be `DateInterval::createFromDateString('00:01:05')->format(arg);` but unfortunately, there is no argument to [`format`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) that would return the total number of seconds (unlike total number of days).

Comment: @Glavić This other question is newer than this one.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The quick way:

```
echo strtotime('01:00:00') - strtotime('TODAY'); // 3600
```

Comment: yes, the quick way in lines-of-code, but not quick in terms of speed -- strtotime() is a very slow function.

Comment: @Spudley: Actually it's not, compared to a `list`,`explode`,`mktime` combination. Benchmarking it tells me `strtotime` is faster, although who cares, it's micro-optimization.

Comment: I'd like to see some benchmarks on that. `strtotime()` does a lot of work with the string to parse it; I'd be very surprised if it can run quicker than mktime(). (To be honest though, multiplying out as per the original question is still probably the quickest option).

Comment: `echo strtotime('1970-01-01 01:00:00'); // 3600` would be faster than doing both strtotime calls.

Comment: Just a thought - I suspect the clock isn't frozen between function calls, so if you happened to hit midnight between calls you'd get the wrong answer - you can avoid this by hard-coding a date in for both calls instead of 'TODAY'.

Answer (score 11):

This should do the trick:

```
list($hours,$mins,$secs) = explode(':',$time);
$seconds = mktime($hours,$mins,$secs) - mktime(0,0,0);
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I edited your answer. If you leave off the optional `$month`, `$day`, and `$year` parameters from `mktime()`, it uses the current month, day, and year. So you need to subtract the seconds since the current date at midnight to get just the seconds from the specified `$time`.

Comment: @Travesty3 - no problem; editing answers is part of the ethos of this site, so if you see one that needs editing, go right ahead and edit it.

Comment: @Travesty3: I think that setting date to 1970-1-1 would be faster, since it is one `mktime` call instead of 2. Use example: `$seconds = mktime($hours,$mins,$secs,1,1,1970);`

Answer (score 8):

I think the **easiest method** would be to use `strtotime()` function:

```php
$time = '21:30:10';
$seconds = strtotime("1970-01-01 $time UTC");
echo $seconds;
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/84739)</kbd>

---

Function [`date_parse()`](http://php.net/date-parse) can also be used for parsing date and time:

```php
$time = '21:30:10';
$parsed = date_parse($time);
$seconds = $parsed['hour'] * 3600 + $parsed['minute'] * 60 + $parsed['second'];
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/84731)</kbd>

Comment: UTC is very useful here since daylight savings time can mess things up.

Answer (score 1):

**This function also supports input without hour or minute**

```
$timeInSecs = function ($tym) {
  $tym = array_reverse(explode(':',$tym));
  $hr = $tym[2] ?? 0;
  $min = $tym[1] ?? 0;
  return $hr*60*60 + $min*60 + $tym[0];
};

echo $timeInSecs('1:1:30') . '<br>'; // output: 3690
echo $timeInSecs('1:30') . '<br>'; // output: 90
echo $timeInSecs('30') . '<br>'; // output: 30
```